# Trying to dupe inputs/textareas with variables

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to add a button, that when I click it - a list of questions appear (with textareas/inputs), every textarea/input has his own ID and I'm trying to get all of the answers **printed into one form**.

```
<h5>QUESTION BULK 1/h5>
    <div id="question1">
        <h4">#1</h4>
        <p>Relative name?: <input id="a_relative">
        <p>Age: <input id="a_age">
        <p>What makes him your relative?: <input id="a_what">
    </div>
```

I'm trying to get a button to make it add that bulk of questions, so the user can add the relevant amount.
e.g:

```
<button onClick="clickMe()">Add</button>
```

All of the data from the inputs should be later taken and put into a certain "answer sheet" form.
 e.g:

```
function clickMe() {
  var relative = document.getElementById("a_relative").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("a_age").value;
  var what = document.getElementById("a_what").value;
  var generatedForm = " Name: "+relative+"\n\
  Relative age: "+age+"\n\
  Reason he/she is your relative: "+what+".";

  document.getElementById("X").value = clickMe // put everything in a textarea of example, 
}
```

Comment: And the problem you're having is...?

Answer (score 0):

Try using JQuery it makes id that you do not have to use

```
 document.getElementById("a_relative").value;
```

Comment: Didn't quite understand? I need to get multiple variables from a number of text inputs (don't know how many) and put it all in a form.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution using modern JS methods.

```js
// Use an array to contain the questions
const questions = [

 // Each question has an id, question text, and an
 // object containing the input information
 { id: 1, text: 'Name', input: { el: 'input', type: 'text' } },
 { id: 2, text: 'Age', input: { el: 'input', type: 'number' } },
 { id: 3, text: 'How', input: { el: 'textarea' } },
];

// Grab and cache the elements from the page
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
const add = document.querySelector('.add');
const show = document.querySelector('.show');

// Add event listeners for the buttons
add.addEventListener('click', handleAdd, false);
show.addEventListener('click', handleShow, false);

// When add button is clicked...
function handleAdd() {

  // ...produce html for each question in the array...
  const html = questions.map(question => {
    return createQuestionHTML(question);
  }).join('');

  // ...and add it to the form.
  form.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
}

function createQuestionHTML(question) {

  // Grab the properties/values from the question object
  const { id, text, input: { el, type } } = question;

  // Based on the input type choose whether an input
  // or a textarea should be displayed.
  // Ensure they have an answer class, and a data attribute
  // with question text
  let input = type === 'input'
    ? `<${el} type=${type} class="answer" data-to="${text}" />`
    : `<${el} class="answer" data-to="${text}"></${el}`;

  // Return a section containing a heading of the question text,
  // and the appropriate input element
  return (
    `<section class="question">
      <h5>${id} - ${text}</h5>
      ${input}
    </section>`
  );
}

// When the show button is clicked...
function handleShow() {

  // ...select all the elements with the answer class within the form
  const answers = form.querySelectorAll('.answer');

  // Hide the form
  main.classList.add('hidden');

  // Log the value and data-to attribute text to console
  [...answers].forEach(({ value, dataset }) => {
    output.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div>${dataset.to} => ${value}`);
  });
}
```

```css
form, .buttons { margin-bottom: 1em; }
h5 { margin-bottom: 0.2em; }
.hidden { display: none }
```

```html
<section class="main">
  <form></form>
  <section class="buttons">
    <button class="add">Add questions</button>
    <button class="show">Show answers</button>
  </section>
</section>
<div id="output" />
```

Comment: How can I log it into HTML and not console.log?

Comment: Just create a new element where the data should go. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but look at my original code, I am trying to get everything into variables, and then to put it all in a /form/ that the user will copy from a textarea.

Comment: So, create a new form with the textarea and add the text/values. This is only an example.